# Docker-compose communication issues between a Go app and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up my basic Go app to make a connection to a Postgres database. I have both being spun up as services using docker-compose. When I run `docker-compose up`, I end up getting a timeout error when the Go app tries to connect to Postgres. Something is wrong or missing that is preventing my Go app from being able to make a connection to Postgres.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/go # set up GOPATH in container to reference modules
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}  # this is `postgres`
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}  # this is an empty string
    volumes:
      - $GOPATH/pkg/mod:/go/pkg/mod

  db:
    image: postgres:11.3
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ../db/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

main.go

```golang
import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func main() {
    dbConn, err := sql.Open("postgres", "sslmode=disable host=db port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres connect_timeout=30")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error defining connection to database: %v", err)
    }
    defer func() { _ = dbConn.Close() }()

    // This forces the connection to be created
    err = dbConn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening connection to database: %v", err)
    }
    log.Println("Never get here because we timeout...")
}
```

I expect to make the connection and get to the end of `main.go`. Instead, I get the following error: `error opening connection to database: dial tcp <container-ip>:5432: i/o timeout`

I've tried starting the Postgres container first (`docker-compose up db`), to make sure it was ready, then spinning up my Go app (`docker-compose up api`). Same error.

I've logged into the Postgres container and connected to Postgres by using the connection string, manually: `psql "sslmode=disable host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres connect_timeout=30"` (notice that only the `host` field changed from `db` to `localhost`, as compared to the connection string used in the `main.go` code, above). This works, so the connection string is fine.

When logged in to the Postgres container, I've verified that there is a database named `postgres` that I use in the `dbname` field in the connection string:

```sh
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

I've also tried making my own database and using that in my connection string.

In the `main.go` code, above, I've also tried switching the `sql.Open` line out for the alternative approach:

```golang
c, err := pq.NewConnector("sslmode=disable host=db port=5432 user=postgres dbname=postgres connect_timeout=30")
dbConn = sql.OpenDB(c)
```

If I run my app with `go run main.go` (not running in a container) and make sure to switch the `host` to `localhost` in the Postgres connection string, it works fine. So, it's something to do with the communication between my app's container and the Postgres container.

Comment: Try adding password fotr superuser for your database. As documentation for `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` states `The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so you may notice a password is not required when connecting from localhost (inside the same container). However, a password will be required if connecting from a different host/container`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to my example docker-compose file (with mysql, postgres is the same way)

```
version: '3'
services:
  application:
    image: dangminhtruong/truyencotich:v1
    container_name: truyencotich
    ports:
    - 80:8080
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    volumes:
     - .:/app
    tty: true
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 8080
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: truyencotichDB
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rivendell
      MYSQL_USER: truyencotich
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 789852
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 789852
    volumes:
      - ./database/exported/exported.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/rivendell.sql
    expose:
    - 3306
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
```

And then I connect by following (we connect to mysql db by host name now is mysql container name - truyencotichDB)

```
package database 

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func DBConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    dbDriver := "mysql"
    dbUser := "root"
    dbPass := "789852"
    dbName := "rivendell"
    db, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbUser+":"+dbPass+"@tcp(truyencotichDB)/"+dbName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
```

Comment: Great! Three things from here that fixed my docker-compose.yml.

1) I didn't have a correct `version` specified, to indicate the compose file version (3.4)

2) I added the `depends_on` field in my `api` service to have it wait for `db` to start, first

3) I added an `expose` field for the `db` service exposing ports 5432, for the `api` service to access

Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose.yml misses a link to `db`, i.e., it should look like

```
services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/go # set up GOPATH in container to reference modules
      - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}  # this is `postgres`
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}  # this is an empty string
    volumes:
      - $GOPATH/pkg/mod:/go/pkg/mod
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:11.3
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ../db/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. It looks like the `links` feature is deprecated, though (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links). You don't happen to know how you'd set this up with the "user-defined networks" feature that Docker recommends, do you?